# When deploying iPad App to device, it just shows a blank screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I just created a simple iPad app and dragged a few components on its mainform.

When I debug it in the Simulator it works fine, but when debugging it on an actual iPad I only get a blank screen. What may I do wrong?

Comment: Does a completely blank iPad project using one of the XCode templates install and run on your iPad?

Comment: Yeah it works and for some reason I can also see the interface now on the iPad. I don't know whats wrong with my old project.

Comment: Strange one alright. Those error's don't look familiar to me anyways, So I'm no assistance to you. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console log of the device using the Organizer in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

open main window's xib file and go to first tab in inspector and select "Visible at launch"  in window property.

Comment: That didn't work as well. Do I have to assign the view to the window somehow?